# Get XElement from XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
```

I load xml into `XDocument`

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

and next i try to find `XElement` contains **Body**

I tried

```
XElement bodyElement = xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Body", "s")).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
XElement bodyElement = xDoc.Descendants("Body").FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
XElement bodyElement = xDoc.Elements("Body").FirstOrDefault();
```

but `bodyElement` always is `null`.

If I try add namespace

```
XElement bodyElement = xDoc.Descendants("s:Body").FirstOrDefault();
```

I got an error about `:`.

If I remove **s** from XML

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
```

Everything works.

How to get `XElement` containing **Body**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to look in a namespace with a URI of "s" - it doesn't have that URI. The URI is `"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`. I'd also suggest avoiding `XName.Get` and just using `XNamespace` and the `XName +(XNamespace, string)` operator:

```
XNamespace s = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XElement body = xDoc.Descendants(s + "Body").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly.

Comment: @BWA, If you have trouble with receiving XML with varying namespaces you can also try LocalName: `xDoc.Descendants().Where (x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("Body", StringComparison.Ordinal))`

Comment: @Crowcoder: If you're going to do an ordinal comparison, just use `==`... but comparing `LocalName` values would rarely be a good thing to do, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for that tip. Regarding `LocalName`, I agree, but I have had cases where xml coming from different clients arrive with very different namespaces.

Comment: @Crowcoder: I agree it can happen - but that's usually a sign of bad processes which should be fixed, IMO :)